# jquery call knockout method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

For some reason I want to call knockout method in jQuery.

Knockout viewModel is already binding. I don't know how to call it in jQuery.

Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready() {
  form_submit();
}

function form_submit() {
  var form = $('#form');
  var serializedData = form.serialize();
  $.get("{% url 'search:search' %}", serializedData, function(response) {
    AppViewModel.count(response.count); // I tried this, it says undefined is not a function
    //Then I tried:
    var newModel = new AppViewModel();
    newModel.count(response.count); //No errors, but UI doesn't change. I know it's because I'm not binding it. But I don't think I can binding it, because only 1 ko.binding allowed.
}

function AppViewModel() {
   var self = this;
   self.count = ko.observable(count); //Assume I initially assigned some value to count.
   //some other code below not related to this question.
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: `$(document).ready() { form_submit(); }` is not valid javascript

Comment: yeah, i missed some parts of code... thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you assign the result of calling `new AppViewModel` to a variable before applying the bindings on it? Then you can reference that variable inside your jQuery `get` callback.

Something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    form_submit();
});

var vm = new AppViewModel();

function form_submit() {
    var form = $('#form');
    var serializedData = form.serialize();
    $.get("{% url 'search:search' %}", serializedData, function(response) {
        vm.count(response.count);
    });
}

function AppViewModel() {
   var self = this;
   this.count = ko.observable(count);
}


ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

You can also just bind to your form's submit event which should simplify some of your code organization.

For example, in the following HTML, I'm binding to my form's submit event:

```
<div id="myHTML">
    <form data-bind="submit: myFormHandler">
        <!-- form inputs here -->
    </form>
</div>
```

Then in my view model, I'd have the following:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.count = ko.observable();

    this.myFormHandler = function(formElement) {
        var self = this;
        var serializedData = $(formElement).serialize();
        $.get("{% url 'search:search' %}", serializedData, function(response) {
            self.count(response.count);
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var vm = new AppViewModel();

    ko.applyBindings(vm, $("#myHTML")[0]);
});
```

Note that in the above example, I'm scoping my bindings to the `myHTML` div.

Comment: Do you mean data-bind in form? That's another question. I wanted to do it but I can only find how to do binding in text input. I didn't find how to do data bind of multi-choice in django form :(, please give me some clues. Thanks!

Comment: Just try it, it doesn't work, and also cause error in other part of my code.

Comment: @Hunter1010 that code should work... what error are you seeing?

Comment: Thanks, but it seems i cannot do it in this way. My form is very complicated. some button in it is not used for submit. That's one of reasons I don't want to bind them and use knockout. I tried other codes, and it's not work.

Comment: I found this: http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/hEjWz/. I change the view model dictionary to a function and it doesn't work. Which means if I change my view model function to dict, it can be used. But it perhaps will make my exit code not work...

Comment: Ok... you don't have to have a submit button for this to work, for the record. You can bind a function to any click on some element in your form or some user interaction if it's not a click. It would be the same concept as the approach I presented. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Let me try it :)